# Python Logging how to change logging configuration in all containers without restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a python application that is deployed on multiple containers. Is there any way I can change the logging configuration on all containers without forcing a new deployment or container restart. A simple use case can be to change log level for a particular logger for a specific period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Python logging module is pretty powerful and it includes a logging configuration server that you can access via network, so you can send a new config to all your container.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#configuration-server-example

Comment: Does that mean starting a listener every time in my application ?

Comment: I guess so yes.

Comment: Hey @Loki, i guess logging.config.listen listens to a port on the localhost . Does this also listen to a remote server ?